# $f(t)$ where $t$ is a time index

Tags: functions

This may be a silly question but I was wondering how to interpret f(0) for something like:
$$
f(t) = \sum_{t=1}^T \log(g(t))
$$

or if this doesn't make any sense altogether?

The motivation for this is that I'm working with the following:
for the operator: $\Delta A(t) = A(t+1)-A(t)$, let :

$$
\Delta C = \sum^{T-1}_{t=0} [~~H(\pi(t+1)~|~\mu(t+1))~~ - ~~H(\pi(t)~|~\mu(t+1))~~]
$$
Where $H (\pi(t+1)|\mu(t+1)) = \sum^n_{i=1}\pi_i(t) \log \frac{\pi_i(t)}{\mu_i(t+1}$ is the relative entropy.

I believe this implies that:
$$
C = \sum_{t=1}^{T-1}H(\pi(t)~|~\mu(t+1))
$$
and I want to find $C(0), C'(0) $

Comment: The expression on the right is independent of $t$. It is a function of $T$. Did you mean $f(T)$ on the left?

Comment: Assuming you mean $f(T)$, the convention is that $f(0)=0$, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum).

Comment: @5xum I updated the question to include why I was asking, the way that the $\Delta$ operator is specified implies that it should be $f(t)$ so I am confused about what $C$ is a function of..

Comment: @5xum or is it that C is a function of $\pi(t)$?

Comment: @dimebucker91 $C$, as you wrote it, is clearly not a function of $t$. It **is** a funcion of $T$. The sum $$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$$ is **never** a function of $i$, it is a function of $n$!

Comment: @5xum so then $C(T) = \sum^{T-1}_{t=0} H(\pi(t) |\mu(t+1) )$, which makes it incompatible with $\Delta C = C(T+1) - C(T)$ doesn't it? I guess my question boils down to, if you were given $\Delta C$ as I have written it, what is $C(T)$ ?